# Is there a way to resolve this error: "CloudKit integration requires does not support ordered relationships."

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, ios13

I'm trying to use Apple's [CoreDataCloudkitDemo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/synchronizing_a_local_store_to_the_cloud) app. I've only changed the app settings per their README document. On running the demo, I'm getting the error: "CloudKit integration requires does not support ordered relationships."

(The weird grammar in the title is included in the app)

The console log shows:

```
Fatal error: ###persistentContainer: Failed to load persistent stores:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=CloudKit integration requires does not support ordered relationships. The following relationships are marked ordered:  
Post: attachments
```

There is the same error for the "Tags" entity.

I'm using Xcode 11.0 beta 4 (11M374r).

I've only changed the bundle identifier, and set my Team Id.

I removed the original entitlements file - no errors in resulting build.

I've not changed any code from the original.

Does anyone have a workaround, or preferably, a fix? Or did I do something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, select **CoreDataCloudKitDemo.xcdatamodeld** -> **Post** -> **RelationShips**, select **attachments** relationship, on the Inspect panel, deselect **Ordered**, then do the same thing on the **tags** relationship.

Secondly, there will be some errors in the code now, because we unchecked the **Ordered** option, the property of `attachments` and `tags` in the generated NSManagedObject may changed from `NSOrderedSet?` to `NSSet?`. So we could change these error lines of code like below:

Origin:
`guard let tag = post?.tags?.object(at: indexPath.row) as? Tag else { return cell }`

Changed:
`guard let tag = post?.tags?.allObjects[indexPath.row] as? Tag else { return cell }`

Finally, you can run the code now. ;-)

---

Further more, on WWDC19 Session 202, the demo shows they set both attachments and tags relationships as **Unordered**, so I think there's something wrong in the given demo project.

Comment: Here is a patch to make the example project work:
https://github.com/ralfebert/SynchronizingALocalStoreToTheCloud/commit/e836893f5a669390090638d89a4f19021e1d2b11

(using allObjects works, but it's a bit dangerous because the order is undefined)

Comment: I also had to explicitly set the iCloud container id, otherwise it gets a different one for iOS and Catalyst which leads to a build error:
https://github.com/ralfebert/SynchronizingALocalStoreToTheCloud/commit/c6306c30864422c2f6cb0cecb56c2b2374e5e6e0

Comment: I submitted a bug report about the problem (FB6902557)

Comment: @RalfEbert That's cool!!! Thanks a lot! I'm now using this solution and using the create date to sort the items.